# how to use edit option in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to edit a todo and created a method to show text input on toggle edit button. but when it is clicked it embeds input box in all the todos present there.

Here's the code

```
<template>

  <div class="todos mt-4 mx-auto">

    <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':currentTodo.completed}" v-for="currentTodo in todos" :key="currentTodo.id">

      <div class="todo-details">
        <div v-show="!isEditing">
          <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete(currentTodo)">
          <span>{{currentTodo.title}}</span>
        </div>

        <div v-show="isEditing">
          <EditTodos></EditTodos>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="todo-controls">

        <button class="button btn-primary mx-2 edit" @click="edit" >
          <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="button btn-danger del" @click="deleteTodo(currentTodo.id)">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </button>

      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

</template>

<script>

import EditTodos from './EditTodo'

export default {
  components: {
    EditTodos,
  },
  props: ['todos'],

  data (){
    return {
      isEditing:false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    markComplete: function(currentTodo){
      currentTodo.completed = !currentTodo.completed
    },
    deleteTodo: function(id){

      let newTodos ;
      newTodos = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)

      // Send up to parent
      this.$emit("new-todos",newTodos)

    },
    edit: function(){
      this.isEditing = !this.isEditing
    }
  },


}
```

And code for the other component is

```
<template>

  <div>

    <input type="text" >
    <button>
      update & close
    </button>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SEL5.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYhWc.png)

In the first component used loops to render the todo's and in the other component i just used the condiitonal to render the edit input box whenever edit button is clicked

I want to show to input box only in that todo item whose edit button is fired

Comment: "isEditing" must be a property of "currentTodo" otherwise it will be a global variable

Comment: I am a beginner to vue. Can you tell me how i can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of toggling an `isEditing` boolean you should store the todo that's being edited (or its ID), and then while looping you display edit form only when `currentTodo.id === editedTodo.id`.

That being said, this kind of logic would be better handled within a Todo component (with its own checkbox which shows it's own editing input).